# Unable to access MongoDB installed on a GCE VM from client desktop

Tags: remote-access, google-compute-engine, mongodb

So I installed MongoDB v4.0 on an Ubuntu 18.10 VM running on Google Compute Engine. Installed successfully, working well with the `mongo` shell via SSH. Now I wanted to access the database remotely from my desktop.

Following [this](https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/mongodb-auth/) guide, I edited my `/etc/mongod.conf` file and commented out the `bind_ip` line in the following code:

`net:`

`port: 27017`

`#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1`

Restarted the service `service mongod restart`

Also opened the TCP port 27017 on the Google Cloud Platform Firewall.

However, the database is still inaccessible via all means, i.e. the `mongo` shell installed on my local machine, MongoDB Compass, the `server_ip:27017` format on Google Chrome, all fail to connect.

I ran `sudo netstat -tlnp` via SSH on the VM,

I only got the following line for MongoDB:

`tcp      0    0 127.0.0.1:27017       0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN    18490/mongod`

The `0.0.0.0` line which should have been there indicating that it is open to all connections was still missing.

Can this possibly be a configuration error or is some internal firewall blocking the connection?

Edit: I even made sure iptables isn't causing this.
Issued the commands

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A OUTPUT  -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. It was indeed a configuration problem and not a firewall issue.

Apparently MongoDB no longer works fine with `bindIp: 0.0.0.0` or commenting out `bindIp` entirely.

What worked is that I removed the bindIp line and replaced it with

> bindIpAll: true

So the final code looks like:

> net:
>
> port: 27017
>
> bindIpAll: true
>
> #  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

P.S. If you're doing this on your server, don't forget to enable MongoDB authentication

Uncomment the line `security:`
And add `authorization: 'enabled'` below that.

> security:
>
> authorization: 'enabled'